# Common EJB Client Jar for various modules under the same EAR

Tags: ejb-3.1

Hello brothers in code!

First question here so I'll try my best to respect all the standards. Correct me if I skip anything and I'll fix it right away.

I'm kind of confused about the approach I should take with my application. I have several EJB projects and JSF projects under the same EAR and, of course, I'd like to define some local interfaces for all of the EJB projects. I have a persistence layer with a couple of modules insipierd by the EAO pattern and an access point to the bussiness layer through a Session Façade.

My intention is to make a "SharedInterfaces" Jar that contains all the Client interfaces (All EJB Client jars in one, if I must say) and all the Interfaces that the entities will implement so I can abstract the projects between themselves (no dependencies, just common interfaces to work together).

How can I turn this "SharedInterfaces" project into a common EJB CLient Jar to be used by all the modules? On the other hand, I can make some interface extension so I don't have to configure a project... still I'm not sure if this common project is on the "best practices" approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I pretty much figured it out myself.

The SharedInterfaces project defines the interfaces to be commonly used and when I want to make a LocalInterface for an EJB I simply leave that interface blank and extend the one I defined on SharedInterfaces. The container seems to handle it allright because the interface is a local interface after all (sort of).

Just for the sake of clarity I'll add a simple example of what I did. This is the local interface I create for an EJB:

```
package org.myapp.managers;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface UserManagerLI extends IUserManager{

}
```

Then, on SharedInterfaces I simply add the interface IUserManager:

```
public interface IUserManager {

    public IUser newUser(); 
    public void saveOrUpdate(IUser u, boolean hashPass);    
    public void deleteUser(IUser u);    
    public boolean checkUserAvailability(String username);  
    public IUser getUser(String username);

}
```

Then, to use it I simply made the injection as usual:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LogInBean {

    @EJB
    private IUserManager userManager;

        // Attributes, Setters, Getters and methods

}
```

Of course, one should ALWAYS be careful about what does he expose. Thinking of the interfaces as contracts of service, one should not be able to access functions he is not supossed to access.